# JavaFX: How to select and delete multiple objects in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

How can I select and delete multiple objects in `TableView` ?

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
    public TableView<Student> fxClassroom;
    public void deleteStudent(){
        ObservableList<Student> studentSelected, allStudents;
        allStudents = fxClassroom.getItems();
        studentSelected = fxClassroom.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        studentSelected.forEach(allStudents::remove);
    }
}
```

But in eclipse, I kept getting this error:

> Type mismatch cannot convert void to ObservableList

Comment: notice that `setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)` doesn't return `ObservableList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public class Controller implements Initializable{
    public TableView<Student> fxClassroom;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
      ....
    fxClassroom.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
      ....
    }

        public void deleteStudent(){
            ObservableList<Student> studentSelected, allStudents;
            allStudents = fxClassroom.getItems();
            studentSelected = fxClassroom.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            allStudents.removeAll(studentSelected);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to enable Multiple Selection on your Table

`myTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`

This will enable to the user to select multiple items using the Ctrl key.

Then, in the Event of your "Delete" button, you have to do something like this:

```
ObservableList<MyDisplayedObject> SelectedItemsOfTable=tblProductos.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

if(SelectedItemsOfTable.size()>0){
   //Do your Stuff here
}
```

Where "MyDisplayedObject" is the class of the objects you're displaying on your TableView.

Answer (score 0):

```
fxClassroom.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

This enables you to select multiple rows in the table.

```
ObservableList<Student> list = fxClassroom.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
fxClassroom.getItems().removeAll(list);
```